# How can I change the output pin9 and pin10 into pin5 and pin6?

Tags: arduino, pwm

```
int i = 0;
int x = 0;
bool OK = 0;
#define led_on digitalWrite(2, HIGH)
#define led_off digitalWrite(2, LOW)

float h = 0;
int volvalue=0;
int battvalue=1024;
int temp=0;
int sinPWM[] = {0, 16, 32, 48, 65, 81, 97, 113, 129, 145, 161, 177, 192, 208, 224, 239, 255, 270, 286, 301, 316, 331, 346, 361, 376, 390, 405, 419, 434, 448, 462, 475, 489, 503, 516, 529, 542, 555, 567, 580, 592, 604, 616, 628, 639, 651, 662, 672, 683, 693, 704, 714, 723, 733, 742, 751, 760, 768, 777, 785, 793, 800, 807, 814, 821, 828, 834, 840, 845, 851, 856, 861, 865, 870, 874, 877, 881, 884, 887, 890, 892, 894, 896, 897, 898, 899, 900, 900, 900, 900, 899, 898, 897, 896, 894, 892, 890, 887, 884, 881, 877, 874, 870, 865, 861, 856, 851, 845, 840, 834, 828, 821, 814, 807, 800, 793, 785, 777, 768, 760, 751, 742, 733, 723, 714, 704, 693, 683, 672, 662, 651, 639, 628, 616, 604, 592, 580, 567, 555, 542, 529, 516, 503, 489, 475, 462, 448, 434, 419, 405, 390, 376, 361, 346, 331, 316, 301, 286, 270, 255, 239, 224, 208, 192, 177, 161, 145, 129, 113, 97, 81, 65, 48, 32, 16};
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(12, INPUT);
  cli();
  TIMSK1=(0<<ICIE1) | (0<<OCIE1B) | (0<<OCIE1A) | (0<<TOIE1);
  TCCR1A=(0<<COM1A1) | (0<<COM1A0) | (0<<COM1B1) | (0<<COM1B0) | (1<<WGM11) | (0<<WGM10);
  TCCR1B=(0<<ICNC1) | (0<<ICES1) | (1<<WGM13) | (1<<WGM12) | (0<<CS12) | (0<<CS11) | (1<<CS10);
  TCNT1=0x00;
  ICR1=900;
  OCR1A=0x00;
  OCR1B=0x00;
  sei();
}
ISR(TIMER1_OVF_vect) {
  
  if (i > 175) {
    i = 0;
    OK = !OK;
    if(OK==0) TCCR1A=(1<<COM1A1) | (0<<COM1A0) | (0<<COM1B1) | (0<<COM1B0) | (1<<WGM11) | (0<<WGM10);
    else      TCCR1A=(0<<COM1A1) | (0<<COM1A0) | (1<<COM1B1) | (0<<COM1B0) | (1<<WGM11) | (0<<WGM10);
    
    if(volvalue>512 && h>0.1)  h-=0.01;
    if(volvalue<512 && h<0.99) h+=0.01;
    battvalue=analogRead(A0);
  }

  x = h * sinPWM[i];
  i = i + 1;
  if (OK == 0) {
    OCR1A = x;
  }
  if (OK == 1) {
    OCR1B = x;
  }
  if(i==150)
  {
    volvalue=analogRead(A1);
  }
}

void loop() {
  if(digitalRead(12)==LOW) 
  {
    while(digitalRead(12)==LOW){}
    Serial.println(battvalue);
    Inverter();
  }



}
 int Inverter()
{
  Serial.println(battvalue);
  temp=0;
  battvalue=1024;
  led_on;
  h=0.1;
  TCCR1A=(1<<COM1A1) | (0<<COM1A0) | (1<<COM1B1) | (0<<COM1B0) | (1<<WGM11) | (0<<WGM10);
  TIMSK1=0x01;
  OCR1A=OCR1B=0x00;
  while(1)
   {
    if(battvalue<575)   //Low batt protect
    temp++;
    else temp=0;
    if(temp>10)
    {
      TCCR1A=(0<<COM1A1) | (0<<COM1A0) | (0<<COM1B1) | (0<<COM1B0) | (1<<WGM11) | (0<<WGM10);
      TIMSK1=0x00;
      OCR1A=OCR1B=0x00;
      while(1)
      {
        led_on;
        delay(200);
        led_off;
        delay(200);
        if(digitalRead(12)==LOW) 
        {
          while(digitalRead(12)==LOW){}
          Inverter();
        }
      }
    }

    if(digitalRead(12)==LOW)  // Button off
        {
          while(digitalRead(12)==LOW){}
          led_off;
          while(1)
          {
            TCCR1A=(0<<COM1A1) | (0<<COM1A0) | (0<<COM1B1) | (0<<COM1B0) | (1<<WGM11) | (0<<WGM10);
            TIMSK1=0x00;
            OCR1A=OCR1B=0x00;
            if(digitalRead(12)==LOW) 
            {
              while(digitalRead(12)==LOW){}
              Inverter();
            }
          }
        }
     if(h>0.99 && volvalue<100)  //Short protect
        {
          digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
          TCCR1A=(0<<COM1A1) | (0<<COM1A0) | (0<<COM1B1) | (0<<COM1B0) | (1<<WGM11) | (0<<WGM10);
          TIMSK1=0x00;
          OCR1A=OCR1B=0x00;
          while(1)
          {
            led_on;
            delay(200);
            led_off;
            delay(200);
            if(digitalRead(12)==LOW) 
            {
              while(digitalRead(12)==LOW){}
              Inverter();
            }
          }
       }
   }
   
}
```

Comment: More info required. We don't even know what this is running on.

Comment: We can't know, because -- assuming that you are using some processor -- we don't know _what_ processor.  Please **edit your question**.  At the **very top** tell us what processor you're using (give a part number, not just "PIC16" or "Arduino"), what you're trying to do with those pins -- especially if you're trying to use some special-purpose I/O like SPI or UART or timers or whatever, but even if it's just GPIO.  Mention which are inputs or outputs, etc.

Comment: Do you use the pins as GPIO or something special?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Just a guess: pin 9 and 10 may be hardware assigned PWM outputs of timer1. If so, a lot of the code must be modified using another timer

Comment: I use this code to run a PWM for  Inverter(12-220V). I use arduino UNO .The pins 9 and 10 are used as PWM outputs. Where exactly in the code is using the pins 9 and 10 as outputs? I want to change the outputs into pin5 and pin6. @Jens

Comment: @ΜάνοςΣυλλιγαρδάκης, please add that information **into your question**. Don't hide it in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

The program uses high frequency hardware PWM capabilities of TIMER1. The outputs are fix assigned in hardware to pin 9 (OC1A) and 10 (OC1B). There is no option to reassign them to other outputs.

Pin 5 and 6 are PWM outputs of TIMER0, which is an 8 bit counter. The software is written for a 16 bit counter. TIMER0 is used by the Arduino runtime to provide function millis().

Simple result: You can't.